# The handwriting to text

Tags: handwriting

Can someone help me to convert the image into text?
Thank you for your efforts!

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about the English language.

Comment: There are a number of tools online for this (https://www.ocr2edit.com/convert-to-txt), by the way; but this is not the place for your request.

Answer (score 1):

His English isn't correct, so I'll put it in correct English:

> Hey you!
>
> We used your services and we were very satisfied!
>
> -- Goehujs(?)from Switzerland
>
> In Switzerland, we wash our clothes in the river, so it's cool to see all the technology provided from this country.
>
> XOXO (means "kisses")

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It is very helpful! I hope you have a great day! :)

Comment: The middle part says "Greetings from Switzerland" and the Swiss flag.

Comment: It's also not "Hey you," but "Hey {smiley face}." But I'm inclined to think the entire question should be deleted.